# Different ways to describe the action enter

Tags: expressions

I am from Mexico, currently i am learning this language and i noticed that there are different ways to express this action "Enter" for example:

May i (come in)?
Are you going to (go into) the classroom?
(Get into) my car

As you can see, all of them mean the same in spanish, but in english it's 
different.

Could you please tell me?
All the different ways to express this action.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You might find this Wikipedia article interesting: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Verb_framing#Manner_and_path

Comment: If it’s true those mean the same in Spanish, I will buy you a meal in any restaurant of your  choice.
My bet is safe because there is not now, nor has there ever been, any language in which even two of those things, let alone all three, mean the same.
Most difficult, for me, is how anyone capable of phrasing a Question like that in any language, could so badly misunderstand the underlying idea in English… or in his mother tongue.
Please, find even one half-way respected Mexican academic who agrees with what you’re asking… Come to that, who understands what you’re asking.

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin In Spanish (like most Romance languages) the verb *entrar* includes senses that in English would require different verb constructions. See sumelic's link above - Romance verbs like *entrar* incorporate the "path" information that in English requires different phrasal verb choices.

Answer (score 2):

Especially since you're Mexican, you'll find the link given by @sumelic useful in understanding the origins of words and some background to it.

As for usage, you'll need to pick it up as you go. The application of words has changed over time and some older terms are less used today.

Take the word *Enter*. It does not always mean *come*.

So here are some examples that I hope you'll find useful. This is not a full list but I hope it will help.

1. Enter = go into some place. So in this context, the terms you may use are:

   - get in : *get in the car*
   - step in : *step into the ICU*
   - go in : *go into the classroom*...
   - hop in/on : *hop on and let's go...*
   - come on in : used to welcome someone or call them in.
   - log in/on : used with computers and similar devices. Eg: *I can't seem to log in to the system* or *he claims there's an error while logging in...*
2. Enter = To record

   - record : *did you record the transaction in the ledger?*
   - write down : *did you write down the minutes in the log book?*
   - key in / type : *You should key in those figures before noon*
   - lodge : You should lodge a complaint about that neighbour*.
   - log into/onto : *after you log the temperature into the master sheet*
3. Enter = To accept into

   - accept into : *We accept you into our faculty*
   - admit : *The patient was admitted yesterday*
   - enroll : *The student was enrolled last week*
   - receive : *we receive you into our university with open arms*
4. Enter = Put into

   - put into : *Did you put the marbles into the bottle?*
   - plug into/onto : *before you plug the device into the socket...*
   - push into : *now push the valve into the base*
   - fix : *fix the chip onto the main-board*

Comment: Thank you so much guys, that was very useful, i appreciate your help

Comment: That's exactly what i was looking for.

Comment: Glad you find it useful. Please accept the answer.